# bootstrap3: inline form with labels above fields without using columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) covers only the "labels on the left" case for inline forms. I don't like the solution of splitting the form-groups in different columns.

Is there any other way to get the desired result (labels above fields)?

My code is something like:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should post the code you are working with.

Comment: "_Is there any other way to get the desired result (labels above fields)_" You can write your own css...

Comment: @Takendarkk Sure. I thought maybe it would be something built-in to bootstrap (something that I'm missing), because this seems like a common case to me.

Comment: I would say the built in way is to use columns unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know much of css and bootstrap (obviously), but the accepted answer did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style:

```
.form-inline label {
 display: block;
}
```